# send and receive variable using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send variable to php using javascript and trying to receive back and alert that variable. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function getMessageType(data)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "test.php";
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Here is my Php code:

```
<?php       
$obj = $_POST['data'];
return $obj;
?>
```

this is what I tried:

```
getMessageType('some data'); //function call

function getMessageType(data)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "test.php";
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(data);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
}
```

Php code :

```
<?php       
$obj = $_POST['data'];
echo $obj;
```

Still I am getting blank alert.

Comment: Where is your $_POST variable coming from?   As far as I can see there isn't actually any data passed in your POST method.  Looks like there is no data to extract on the php side, and so nothing is being passed back.  

What happens when you go to you php page?  Do you see anyting?

Comment: I am passing that data when I call `getMessageType(data)` function. and I have checked also, data is coming.

Comment: Do you see your data printed out on the DOM when you visit test.php in your browser?  You dont want to return your data, you want to echo it to the DOM.

Comment: I don't see that.

Comment: isn't this code suppose to send data to php and alert that when echo.

Answer (score 0):

You should `echo` this variable from php side.

```
<?php       
$obj = $_POST['data'];
echo $obj;
```

Also in this case you should use `text/plain` content-type.

Comment: Please change `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` to `text/plain`

Comment: tried `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` still no luck.

Comment: Also try to send `true` value as `string`. `xhr.open('POST', url, 'true');`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning your object.

```
echo $obj;
```

Also you are sending your data request AFTER you are alertingg your data, so you are alerting before you have anything to alert.

Do something like this.

```
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
 xhr.send(data);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
```

Comment: where do you want me to put `echo json_encode($obj);` ?

Comment: You should echo your return data at the end of your php page.  It should replace your return call.

Comment: You still havn't answered my question... do you see your data when you go do test.php?

Comment: well then either, you are not echoing your data.  Or you have no data to echo.  

Good Luck

Comment: Check my answer again, you need to send(data) earlier in your script.

That was a major problem, although I still don't know where you are pulling data from.